# Maven finds "org.foo.Bar" and "org.(some other)foo.Bar" - and the build fails

Tags: scala, maven, build

I'm working on a Scala project that is managed with Maven, all on OS X. When I build the project, I will get errors that look like this:

```
[ERROR] /Users/me/project/MyScalaFile.scala:97: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found: org.foo.Bar
[INFO]  required: org.(some other)foo.Bar
[INFO]  Bar(stuff)
[INFO]     ^
```

Sometimes they will be switched, e.g.

```
[INFO]  found: org.(some other)foo.Bar
[INFO]  required: org.foo.Bar
```

Running "mvn clean" and then rebuilding the project is the only way I've been able to get around this. I would like to avoid doing that (and of course, inexplicable build errors are not good either :P).

Comment: sound like [jar hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_hell#JAR_hell), try to exclude conflicting libraries in `pom.xml` file. also, this might be because of ambigous imports. try to: `import org.(some other)foo.{Bar =>_, _}` instead of `import org.(some other)foo._` (if this is the case )

Comment: How do I determine if two libraries in my pom conflict?

Comment: IntelliJ (Ultimate Edition) has a cool tool that will display lib dependencies as a graph, where conflicting libraries are marked. if you prefer a simpler tool, you could use `mvn dependency:tree` to see all your dependencies. you could search the text for libraries being imported multiple times with different versions.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with a package object that I've created and the case classes I define in it.

Comment: if this is the case, some code samples could help figure out what the problem is...